# create a macro in sas

Tags: macros, sas

I have a report that is generated once a year. each report has the form of the year inside the name - report-2011.xls, report-2012.xls etc. each report contains the following vars: ID, SAL=average monthly salary of that year, Gender (0=male, 1=female), Married (0=not married, 1=married), I need to create a macro that calculates the mean.std,min and max of the salary, per year in accordance to gender type and married type. in the macro I need to include a parameter for the relevant year. 
how do I refer to each type separately in calculating these parameters?
and how do I create a separate parameter for the year var?

Comment: Probably you may need an infile statement / pipe statement to read excel file, and establish the macro for 1) year= 2011,2012..., 2) data steps with where gender = 1/0  ,3) married type =1/0 , 4) call symputx to report the answer.. Please show what you have tried first.

Comment: I don't have a specific file with data  in order to read it into sas, the point is that I need to create a macro that will simulate this process according to the defined parameters. is that possible to do without an actual file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proc summary allows you to control exactly which ways you want to cross the data.

```
%macro report(year);

proc import datafile="/path/to/report-&year..xls"
    out= salary_data                                                                                                                         
    dbms=csv replace ;                                                                                                                       


proc summary data = salary_data;
    class married gender;
    types married gender married*gender;
    var sal;
    output out = salary_results mean(sal) = mean_salary std(sal) = std_salary;

* Print the summary;
proc print; 

* Delete the data and summary after using them;
proc delete data= salary_data salary_results; run;


%mend report;
```

Note that proc summary produces other useful information which you can read about [here](http://www.lexjansen.com/sugi/sugi21/at/045-21.pdf). You can drop them if you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

```
%macro reporting(year, gender, marital_status);
    proc means data=data&year min max std;  * <== you should have separate datasets for different years 
    class gender married ; 

%mend reporting

%reporting( 2015, 1, 1)
```

Is that something you are looking for?

Comment: by %reporting( 2015, 1, 1) I actually generate the required statistics on a report from year 2015, with females that are married? but I actually need to create a macro that will calculate (mean,min,max and std) for salary var for women separately and for man separately, (same goes for marital status).

Comment: in this case using 'class' would be less troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

I macro is just a way to generate code.  So first design the code you want it to generate.  Then you can figure out what parts of it vary and replace those with macro variable references.  The macro variables then become the parameters for your macro.

```
proc import datafile="report-2011.xls" out=report_2011 ; run;
proc means data=report_2011 ;
   class gender married;
run;
```